# Swift: Text label not updating

Tags: swift, macos, label, appdelegate

I have a text label (NSTextField). I want it to pin to the upper left vertex of every object to show an element's number in UI. 
But my label shows only ZERO and doesn't move (it stays in the upper left corner). What I did wrong?

Here is my code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
@IBOutlet weak var drawingView: DrawingView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!


var localArray: [CGPoint] = []

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    label.textColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.15, green: 0, blue: 0.75, alpha: 0.3)
    label.font! = NSFont(name: "Arial Bold", size: 60)!
    label.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()
    label.stringValue = "\(localArray.count/4)"

    for (pointIndex, _) in localArray.enumerate() {

        let point = CGPoint(x: (localArray[(pointIndex/4)+1].x), y: (localArray[(pointIndex/4)+1].y))

        label.sizeToFit()
        label.frame = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: label.bounds.width, height: label.bounds.height))
    }
}
```

And here is my code in DrawingView.swift:

```
   var delegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
   delegate.localArray = myArray.map { return $0.coordSequence()[0] }
```

myArray contains cgpoints.

Am I right putting label parameters inside **applicationDidFinishLaunching** method?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to update NSTextField probably from wrong thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
     label.stringValue = "\((localArray.count/4)+1)"
})
```

Try to investigate you're array i could make assumption that when you set value of the label `localArray.count` is 0. Also keep in mind that you are working with `Int` and if `localArray.count` is 3 so 3/4 will be 0.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.label.stringValue = "\(self.localArray.count/4)"
        })

Comment: if I put **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.label.stringValue = "\((self.localArray.count))"
        })**, result is the same.

Comment: could you simply print self.localArray.count and notice if it is more than 0

Comment: I suppose text label not updating due to applicationDidFinishLaunching method. Seemingly, my label needs another method but I do not know what method are suitable for this situation.

Comment: Yes, I printed it. It's not 0.

Comment: In my case it's all right to get 0 for first four cgpoints. Then 1 for next four cgpoints. And so on.

Comment: try to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910467/changing-the-value-of-nstextfield-doesnt-update-label

Comment: Sorry Oleg Gordiichuk! Could you translate this code into Swift? I'm not good at Obj-C.